# Multiple id's input for select query with oracle bpel dbadapter

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

In Oracle SOA one can do insert multiple records in Database in single transaction.This is supported out of the box and nothing you need to do special to achieve it. If you create database adapter in your BPEL process with INSERT operation it is exposed as collection of object as Input. You can use XSLT to assign that Collection and all records will be inserted in one atomic transaction.

Is there an equivalent feature for pure sql query?

I have a complicated query that requires only a single id for it's input.
But I like this query to be repeated for multiple id's. Rather than defining a for loop and what not, is there a flag/switch/way when creating the bpel process to allow for multiple id's as the input?

Comment: Would something like `INSERT ALL` fulfill this requirement? Here are some examples : https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
create table test (id number(3), name varchar2(20));

insert into test 
  select t.column_value, dbms_random.string('A', 20) 
    from table(sys.odcinumberlist(4, 17, 105, 91, 212)) t;
```

Pure SQL, one `insert`, five rows with defined `id`s. If `id` is varchar use `sys.odcivarchar2list` or define custom type at first.

Comment: You don't have to create any new table. I created test table to show that such insert works, I had to insert sample data somewhere.

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood my question, I was not interested in insert operations, but rather select operations